# EC2 ELB Wildcard SSL Renewal "Invalid Public Key Certificate"

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, ssl-certificate

We have an existing ELB on EC2.  It's got a GoDaddy issued wildcard ssl cert.  I've downloaded the new .crt and gd_bundle.crt from GoDaddy.

In ec2 I go to the load balancer, click the certificate, choose to upload a new cert.  I copy the existing private key into the private key field.  The contents of the new .crt into the public certificate field and the contents of gd_bundle.crt into the certificate chain field.

When I try and save it I get the error "Invalid Public Key Certificate."

The certs are in PEM format (or they seem to be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was missing that my key was not an RSA key, I needed to do the following:

```
openssl rsa -in company.key -out company_rsa.key
```

Comment: Awesome, no idea how I generated it as not an RSA key, but thanks!